# What is a reliable way to reset datetime.now?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been working on a discord bot and with the following, I want to find a difference between D0 and D1 (December 2nd), anytime a message is sent that then prompts delta (difference between current time and 12/2) to be used for either a calculation of day or hour, along with just knowing the day.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

D0 = datetime. now
D1 = datetime(2023, 12 , 2, 8, 0)
delta = D1 - D0
days = int(round((delta.total_seconds() // 86400), 15))
hours = (round((delta.total_seconds() // 3600) - days*24) + 6)

from dateutil.rrule import *
number_weekdays = (rrule(WEEKLY, byweekday=(MO,TU,TH,FR), dtstart=D0,until=D1).count()) - 3

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)

    if message.content.startswith('/Commands'):
            await message.channel.send('/Ben, /Competition, /Meets, /debug, /Code')

    if message.content.startswith('/Competition'):
            await message.channel.send(f'{days} days and {hours} hours until our next competition.')

    if message.content.startswith('/competition'):
            await message.channel.send(f'{days} days and {hours} hours until our next competition.')
    
    if message.content.startswith('/Meets'):
            await message.channel.send(f'{number_weekdays} meets until next competition.')

    if message.content.startswith('/debug'):
            await message.channel.send('What are you Looking For?!')

    if message.content.startswith('/code'):
            await message.channel.send(f'{delta}')
```

I have been working on a Discord Bot and I have looked around, but I have wanted a way to reset the D0 anytime a message including it is sent regarding it.

I have tried to use different ways, such as resetting the bot to refresh the current time, along with

```
def now():
          return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

, I have also seen ways of resetting the variable, but I don't understand how I could do that continuously. I have started to realize the problem with the datetime.now being a set value as I launch the code, but I am wondering if there is another way to easily reset this.

Comment: You will have to call datetime.now inside the function that sends the message. Not set it outside wher it'll only execute once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compute the date information whenever it's requested, not only once, e.g.

```
import dataclasses
import datetime

import dateutil.rrule as rrule


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class CompetitionInfo:
    days: int
    hours: int
    number_weekdays: int


def get_competition_info():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    end_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 2, 8, 0)
    delta = end_date - now
    days = int(round((delta.total_seconds() // 86400), 15))
    hours = round((delta.total_seconds() // 3600) - days * 24) + 6
    rr_count = rrule.rrule(
        rrule.WEEKLY,
        byweekday=(rrule.MO, rrule.TU, rrule.TH, rrule.FR),
        dtstart=now,
        until=end_date,
    ).count()
    number_weekdays = rr_count - 3
    return CompetitionInfo(
        days=days,
        hours=hours,
        number_weekdays=number_weekdays,
    )


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    message_lower = message.content.lower()

    if message_lower.startswith("/competition"):
        ci = get_competition_info()
        await message.channel.send(
            f"{ci.days} days and {ci.hours} hours until our next competition."
        )

    if message_lower.startswith("/meets"):
        ci = get_competition_info()
        await message.channel.send(
            f"{ci.number_weekdays} meets until next competition."
        )
```